# in python printing initialized dictionary as empty

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with three keys and initialize the corresponding value with 1. Following is my code:

```
d = {}
d.fromkeys(range(3),1)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{}
```

Also `d[0][1] = 10` is giving error. I'm a newbie in python, please let me know the reason and work around (if possible). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`dict.fromkeys` returns a new dictionary object you need to reassigned it.

```
d=d.fromkeys(range(3),1)
```

Also since `d[0]` is not an indexable object you can not use `d[0][1]` and it will raise an `TypeError` :

```
>>> d[0][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```